# How to create link for django filter

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-filter

Scenario:

Products can have multiple attributes defined in the database, I want to be able to filter by those attributes.

Since i have not found a way to use dynamic attributes using django-filter, this is currently achieved by using django filter `MethodFilter` which parses the attributes passed as query string as:

`/products?attribute=size_2&attribute=color_red`

url like this is parsed and it works.

The problem is building the url:

I couldn't find a reasonable way to build the url, that would take current search parameters into account and add/replace those parameters.

Django seems to be forcing me to use urlconf but django-filter uses query string parameters.

What i try to achieve is this:

The user is on page `/products?attribute=size_10` which display all products with that size.
When he clicks th link "color red" the new url becomes: `/products?attribute=size_10&attribute=color_red`

Can you point me to the *django way* of implementing this?

Comment: how about putting the filters in a form with method="get"? the browser will automatically put the get parameters for you and you can retrieve them from django

Comment: Ok, but what about opening the link in new window? I'm not sure it will work as expected.

Comment: have you specified anything about opening the link in a new window?

Comment: No, you are right i didn't but i specified it should be a link, not a form with method=get :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you include `"django.core.context_processors.request",` in your middleware
then the request.get is accessible in your templates.

you could then build a filter that will return what 'GET' variables you want when building the link you are talking about.

here is code for one that i did:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def lessonapp_preserved_filters(context, url, dayofweek):
    opts = context.get('opts')
    preserved_filters = context.get('preserved_filters')

    parsed_url = list(urlparse(url))
    parsed_qs = dict(parse_qsl(parsed_url[4]))
    merged_qs = dict()

    if opts and preserved_filters:
        preserved_filters = dict(parse_qsl(preserved_filters))

        match_url = '/%s' % url.partition(get_script_prefix())[2]
        try:
            match = resolve(match_url)
        except Resolver404:
            pass
        else:
            current_url = '%s:%s' % (match.app_name, match.url_name)
            changelist_url = 'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name)
            if changelist_url == current_url and '_changelist_filters' in preserved_filters:
                preserved_filters = dict(parse_qsl(preserved_filters['_changelist_filters']))

        preserved_filters['dayofweek__exact'] = dayofweek

        merged_qs.update(preserved_filters)


    merged_qs.update(parsed_qs)

    parsed_url[4] = urlencode(merged_qs)
    return urlunparse(parsed_url)
```

and then in the template i use it like this:

```
{% lessonapp_preserved_filters adm_url '1' %}
```

Comment: I already have access to request in my template. THe problem is in replacing some get argumets and preserving others.

Comment: which is exactly why you can build a filter to return what you need saved and what you need altered.

Comment: @BlindAndFurious updated my answer with a sample of one i did.

Comment: Hi @warath-coder. Is that a view? Or a middleware? Could you give more details? I am using django 3.0. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BrunoMorabito Its middleware the first line, the next code is a template filter.  Not sure if those things have changed in D3; still using D2

Answer (score 1):

At the end I solved, although the solution is pretty verbose.

---

### Context

I want a multiple choice filter, where the user can filter the brand of the products.
Note that it is ok if the page refreshes every time I click on the multiple choice field.

### Main idea

I build a different link for each field in the multiple choice, by manually adding the search parameters in a view for each link in the filters. Every time the page refreshes new link are created, depending on which choice in the multiple choice is selected.

### Code

The **views.py** looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from .models import Product, Brand
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    queryset_list = Product.objects.order_by('price')
    # Keyworks
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        search = request.GET['search']

        if search:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(description__icontains=search))
            path = request.path
            link = path + '?' + 'search=' + search

            # Brands filter
            brands_list = []
            for query in queryset_list:
                if query.brand.name not in brands_list:
                    brands_list.extend([query.brand.name])
            brand_urls = {}
            brand_active = [False] * len(brands_list)
            if 'brand' not in request.GET:
                for brand in brands_list:
                    brand_urls[brand] = link + '&' + 'brand=' + brand
            else:
                active_filters = [f for f in request.GET['brand'].split(',')]
                if len(active_filters) > 1:
                    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(brand__name__in=active_filters)
                for k, brand in enumerate(brands_list):
                    new_active_filters = active_filters.copy()

                    if brand in new_active_filters:
                        brand_active[k] = True
                        new_active_filters.remove(brand)
                        brand_urls[brand] = link + '&' + 'brand=' + ','.join(new_active_filters)
                    else:
                        brand_active[k] = False
                        new_active_filters.append(brand)
                        brand_urls[brand] = link + '&' + 'brand=' + ','.join(new_active_filters)

    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 12)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_products = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {
        'products': paged_products,
        'values': request.GET,
        'brand_urls': brand_urls,
        'brand_active': brand_active,
    }
    return render(request, 'products/search.html', context)
```

basically, every filter is a url, that contains the query parameters. So I build a different url for every link by adding or removing parameters, depending if the link is active or not.

**search.html** looks like this:

```
        <h2>Brands</h2>
        {% if brand_urls %}
          <ol>
            {% for brand in brand_urls.items %}
              {% if brand_active|my_index:forloop.counter0 is True %}
                <li><input type="checkbox" checked><a href="{{ brand.1 }}">{{ brand.0 }}</a></li>
              {% else %}
                <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="{{ brand.1 }}">{{ brand.0 }}</a></li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ol>
        {% endif %}
```

where **my_index** is a template filter

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def my_index(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try use some js solution.

1. just get all the current attributes from url by  using js ,build  dict.
2. when clicking other attribute button,you can add or replace the attribute in the dict.
3. use this dict to form your url.